# Java: Parsing Input separated by commas

Tags: java, input

Java program:

The input below is just off the top of my head. What I'm looking for is how to take specific portions of input data based on whether they are a string or a primitive type... and here I'm thinking it might be useful to use the comma that separates them somehow.

```
   /* Given input:
   *
   * Massachusetts, Ma, Boston, 10000, 20000
   * California, CA, Los Angeles, 30000, 40000

   * How would you print:

   * Massachusetts    20000
   * California       40000
   */

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in) ;

     while (userInput.hasNextLine()) {
         String state = userInput.nextLine() ;
         Double population = userInput.nextDouble() ;
         String temp = userInput.nextLine() ; // for the new line

         System.out.printf( "%s %2f" , state , population ) ;
     }
}
```

Also I've seen a method called useDelimiter(), I was wondering if that might help break up the input from my Scanner.

Comment: If you're asking questions about code, it's always helpful to add a tag for the language you're using. You may want to [edit] to do so.

Comment: Just read the entire line in and split it on ", ". Then you can get your values with ease.

Comment: Just a heads up on ManoDestras comment. Use `String.split()` if you are expecting your data to be correct (for instance, the first data is city name, second is state something, third is always the same etc etc....

Comment: That's great thank you all! I've never heard of regex or split but I'll give them a go and see what I get, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the string `Massachusetts, Ma, Boston, 10000, 20000`, you can use [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split) to get the array `[Massachusetts, Ma, Boston, 10000, 20000]` (note that this is not a string anymore)

```
String input = "Massachusetts, Ma, Boston, 10000, 20000";
String[] fields = input.split(", ?");
String state = fields[0];
String xx = fields[4];
System.out.println(state+", "+xx); // Massachusetts, 20000
```

Note that the regex `, ?` means *a comma, followed or not by a space*. Also, since this will be user input, you should check if the `fields` array has the required length (in this case, the length should be at least 5 since you're accessing the 4th field)

I guess you can easily adapt your code from this example ;)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-z]+), ([A-z]{2}), ([A-z]+), (\\d+), (\\d+)");
String line = userInput.nextLine();
Matcher lineMatcher = p.matcher(line);
if (lineMatcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(lineMatcher.group(0)); //prints Massachusetts
    System.out.println(lineMatcher.group(1)); //prints Ma
    System.out.println(lineMatcher.group(2)); //prints Boston
    System.out.println(lineMatcher.group(3)); //prints 10000
    System.out.println(lineMatcher.group(4)); //prints 20000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly and your input is of type String, you can use this method:

public String[] split(String regex), where your regex is ",".

It will return you a String[]. You can print each value from this individually using an index, and use Float.parseFloat(String value) to convert your string to a float type.

```
    String userInput = "Massachusetts, Ma, Boston, 10000, 20000";

    userInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); //replaces whitespace
    String[] values = userInput.split(",");

    System.out.println(values[0]);
    System.out.println(values[4]);

    String state = values[0];

    // you probably do not want a float for population
    float population = Float.parseFloat(values[4]);
    System.out.printf( "%s %2f" , state , population );

    // you probably want an integer, so try this
    int integerPopulation = Integer.parseInt(values[4]);
    System.out.printf( "%s %2d" , state , integerPopulation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your code you can make following change:

```
String[] temp = new String[5]; 
while (userInput.hasNextLine()) {
     String input = userInput.nextLine();
     temp[] = input.split(",");
     System.out.printf( "%s %s" ,temp[0] , temp[4] ) ;
 }
```

When you call the nextLine() you can get the entire line for that input. split() it from comma and store it into a temp array. Then print those value according to your requirement. You can convert the data type from the temp array for the value if you need to do any computation.

you can convert the string value to float using this line:

```
Float.valueOf(temp[4]);
```